# What is the .dll file/namespace which includes Localization class

Tags: asp.net, localization, asp.net-mvc-5

I know this is a little stupid that I am asking for a .dll or a namespace which contains Localization while others are asking how to do the localization.

But I have spent half an hour on seeking the reference file or namespace and have got no luck.

I tried to find System.Globalization or similar references in VS 2012 and have found nothing.

Here is the question which I followed to do my coding 
[asp.net mvc multilanguage urls/routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749803/asp-net-mvc-multilanguage-urls-routing)

I am following the code written by Feras Kayyali

```
private  string  GetCurrentCulture()
     {
         string lang;

         // set the culture from the route data (url)

         if (RouteData.Values["lang"] != null &&
            !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(RouteData.Values["lang"].ToString()))
         {
             lang = RouteData.Values["lang"].ToString();
             if (Localization.Locales.TryGetValue(lang, out lang))
             {
                 return lang;
             }
         }
```

As you can see in the code, he used the **Localization.Locales** class which I cannot find from anywhere.

Please help.

Thank you !

Comment: huh??? Where are you guys??

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that is custom code and not part of .NET. I think Locales is a dictionary/lookup to help map a two letter ISO language name to a Windows culture name. Take a look at the [constructor for CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h898a16%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the [Windows National Languages Support reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001.aspx) for culture names.

Comment: thanks you Steve. I'll just leave it here for a few more days to see if there are anybody who can give a hand. cheers